# changing of absolute url

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

Suppose I have two domain
1). abc.com
2). mydomain.com

abc.com contains all UI resources like js, css, images files and mydomain.com contains html files. I have given absolute url for all resources in mydomain.com like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//abc.com/resource/js/abc.js"></script>
```

When I changed abc.com to xyz.com above code give me error because requested files URL was not found. So is there any way to solve it ? Because doamin name or application name can be change in future.

Comment: if the file is hosted on the same domain then you can remove the domain from the url. eg: `/resource/js/abc.js`

Comment: This is primarly the reason for use of  relative path ...

Comment: @andrew file is hosting on a different domain so i can not use relative path.